# Ubuntu Netbook update interrupted

Tags: software-center, aptitude

I was updating my netbook latest version after 1st installation so a lot of updates where there. The updates were downloaded and it was being installed. The computer got switched off in between. Now its not working. I want to just run the command "apt-get upgrade". What is the procedure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say *how* it isn't working. I'm assuming that you mean that your computer won't boot. In that case, you can try booting into a LiveCD or LiveUSB environment (of the same version as your Ubuntu installation). Then, mount your hard drive somewhere. I'm assuming that you mounted it on `/mnt` for the sake of this answer. Any other place is fine, as long as you make the necessary adjustments to my instructions.

```
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo chroot /mnt
```

At this point, you're in your machine with root privileges.

```
apt-get upgrade # Or whatever commands you want.
exit # Back to the live environment...
sudo umount /mnt/{proc,sys}
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade it to Natty 11.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
update-manager -d
```

This will check for update of distribution.

If you don't want to update your distro then simply (in a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

For bringing up a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> while you boot or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> number 2-8 for the relevant tty